# Automatic appointment of room owner should prefer high rep and/or site mods

Tags: feature-request, chat

The [automatic appointment of room owner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#automatic-owner) process currently picks the most active user. A noisy user could easily be a someone that doesn't know the policies of SE. I'd suggest that this process should be changed to prefer the existing site mods or high rep users first, before falling back to the most active user.

Comment: If this actually happens and a problem user does become an owner, someone should ping a mod and we can sort it out.

Comment: What @иɪvэЖєvɪɴ said. Do you have an actual example of this being a problem, or is this just a theoretical thing?

Comment: @balpha, it's not theoretical that a low rep room owner was automatically appointed, but so far it's yet to be a problem. Most of my concern is likely biased from handling chat room flags from other rooms where they do have problem users.

Comment: I would rather it skip mods. Mods can *always* mess with room owner tools, so there isn't any point in having a mod as room owner.

Comment: @Seth, I don't understand the necessity to give an additional person access when an existing person that already has access would be happy to take over. If we're too busy, we can always give out access to someone that has more time. But if the algorithm was changed to pick a high rep user without consideration of mod status, I'd be happy with that.